# Access server running on docker container

Tags: python, docker, server

I am running the StanfordCoreNLP server through my docker container. Now I want to access it through my python script.

Github repo I'm trying to run: https://github.com/swisscom/ai-research-keyphrase-extraction

I ran the command which gave me the following output:

```
docker run -v /home/goorulabs/NarrativeArcse-extraction/sent2vec/torontobooks_unigrams.bin:/sent2vec/pretrained_model.bin -it keyphrase-extraction
/app # cd /stanford-corenlp/
/stanford-corenlp # java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -preload tokenize,ssplit,pos -status_port 9000 -port 9000 -time
out 15000 &
/stanford-corenlp # [main] INFO CoreNLP - --- StanfordCoreNLPServer#main() called ---
[main] INFO CoreNLP - setting default constituency parser
[main] INFO CoreNLP - warning: cannot find edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz
[main] INFO CoreNLP - using: edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz instead
[main] INFO CoreNLP - to use shift reduce parser download English models jar from:
[main] INFO CoreNLP - http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html
[main] INFO CoreNLP -     Threads: 4
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger - Loading POS tagger from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.2 sec].
[main] INFO CoreNLP - Starting server...
[main] INFO CoreNLP - StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at /0.0.0.0:9000
```

Now I tried to access it by specifying the host and the port in the config.ini file but got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1264, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1310, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1259, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb5222fab70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9000): Max retries exceeded with url: /?properties=%7B%22outputFormat%22%3A+%22json%22%2C+%22annotators%22%3A+%22tokenize%2Cssplit%2Cpos%22%7D (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb5222fab70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    kp1 = launch.extract_keyphrases(embedding_distributor, pos_tagger, raw_text, 5,'en')
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/ai-research-keyphrase-extraction/launch.py", line 27, in extract_keyphrases
    tagged = ptagger.pos_tag_raw_text(raw_text)
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/ai-research-keyphrase-extraction/swisscom_ai/research_keyphrase/preprocessing/postagging.py", line 215, in pos_tag_raw_text
    tagged_text = list(raw_tag_text())
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/ai-research-keyphrase-extraction/swisscom_ai/research_keyphrase/preprocessing/postagging.py", line 211, in raw_tag_text
    tagged_data = self.parser.api_call(text, properties=properties)
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/parse/corenlp.py", line 247, in api_call
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 578, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/goorulabs/NarrativeArc/narrativearc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9000): Max retries exceeded with url: /?properties=%7B%22outputFormat%22%3A+%22json%22%2C+%22annotators%22%3A+%22tokenize%2Cssplit%2Cpos%22%7D (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb5222fab70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

The `docker ps` shows a blank column for `PORTS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the log, your service is listening to port 9000 inside the container.
However, from outside you need further information to be able to access it. Two pieces of information that you need:

1. The IP address of the container
2. The external port that docker exports this 9000 to the outside (by default docker does not export locally open ports).

To get the IP address you need to use `docker inspect`, for example via

```
docker inspect keyphrase-extraction | grep IPAddress
```

This should give you a line showing the IP address that you can use from your local host machine to address docker.

Regarding the port, it needs to be explicitly exposed. A quick look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/swisscom/ai-research-keyphrase-extraction/blob/master/Dockerfile) from the repo doesn't show any `EXPOSE` docker commands, so the port 9000 doesn't seem to be exposed by default.

You can expose it by adding `-p9000:9000` to your command (format is `-p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT`) like this:

```
docker run -p9000:9000 -v /home/goorulabs/NarrativeArcse-extraction/sent2vec/torontobooks_unigrams.bin:/sent2vec/pretrained_model.bin -it keyphrase-extraction
```

After you do all of this, you can test whether your port has been successfully exposed for example by using:

```
telnet 172.17.0.1 9000
```

assuming that the above is the IP you get from the first step.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked by just exposing the port. Although the ```docker inspect keyphrase-extraction | grep IPAddress``` command didn't return anything.

Comment: Did you try just `docker inspect keyphrase-extraction` without grepping the line of interest? I guess you've had a different way of finding out the container IP - can't complain about it ;)